How to solve this using describe, columns and shape?
Given a dataframe 'df' use the following commands and analyse the result.
describe()
columns
shape
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/vBDCsoHCytUSLKkLvq851k2b8JOCkF', sep = '|',header = None)
print(df.describe())
print(df.columns)
print(df.shape)

This code leads to a error of:
File "C:\...\example_forest.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/vBDCsoHCytUSLKkLvq851k2b8JOCkF', sep = '|',header = None)
... more lines of traceback ...
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>```


Solve what? What is your issue/question?

You need to provide the traceback problem that you are seeing. We can not see what you are having problems with.

Does this answer your question? urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error

did this solve your question? Did you upvote or mark it as a solved answered?

Import the ssl and use it like this.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ssl # this is the import you need

# this is a way to use the module it is included in the python installation.
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/vBDCsoHCytUSLKkLvq851k2b8JOCkF', sep = ',')

print(df.describe())
print(df.columns)
print(df.shape)

You don't need to pip install this module.
